# CentOS - Apache HTTPS not reading htaccess

Tags: centos, ssl, .htaccess

I have been stuck with an issue with rewrite on apache on CentOS.

If I load my site from HTTP, it works fine. Rewrite rules work. Once I change it to HTTPS, the rewrite rules don't work.

After some tests and browsing through the threads I realised that somehow apache is not picking up the .htaccess file if the website is accessed from HTTPS.

What I did to test was to insert deny from all in the .htaccess file. When I access http://my.domain.com it shows Forbidden error. When I access via https://my.domain.com I can still load the page which means .htaccess is not being read.

I've checked httpd.conf and ssl.conf and also ensured AllowOverride All is set. Is there anywhere else that I could have missed?

Here is my httpd.conf configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/my.domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/my.domain.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/caroot.crt

     ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
     ServerName my.domain.com
     ServerAlias my.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html/
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI MultiViews
            #RewriteEngine on 
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/my.domain.com/logs/ssl-error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/my.domain.com/logs/ssl-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And below is my .htaccess file placed inside /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html/

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Below is the config for port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
     ServerName my.domain.com
     ServerAlias my.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/my.domain.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/my.domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Strange. Can you also post the :80 virtual host for comparison?

Comment: I've updated my question with port 80 config.

Comment: No actual errors in the logs? Is there another default virtualhost? If you change the :433 docroot to add /test/ at the end and put a test index.html in there, does it resolve to that path?

Comment: @JayMcTee When I added a /test it doesn't show any error. And then I looked into ssl.conf and noticed the defaults are set there which shares the same ServerName and ServerAlias as my.domain.com. I placed the <Directory> settings above into that file and reloaded httpd. It works perfectly now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an/the answer then:

Is there another default virtualhost? As everything you've shown seems correct, I suspect there is something else preventing this from working correctly. Most likely, default conf files and/or their default settings.

Check the default settings in ssl.conf, especially ServerName and ServerAlias. Also httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that your global Apache configuration has the below line:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```